# {{ site.title }} not working in jekyll

Tags: jekyll, github-flavored-markdown

this is content of _config.yml file that include two predefined variables

```
name: amarjit singh

description: Mobile CEP blog
```

index.html file uses

```
---
layout: default
---
```

whereas default layout includes below-mentioned div

```
 <div class="intro-header">
    <div class="wrapper-masthead">
     <div class="container">
       <header class="masthead clearfix">
         <div class="site-info">
           <h1 class="site-name"><a href="{{ site.baseurl }}/">{{ site.title }}</a></h1>
           <p class="site-description">{{ site.description }}</p>
         </div>
         <nav>
           <a href="{{ site.baseurl }}/">Blog</a>
           <a href="{{ site.baseurl }}/about">About me</a>
           <a href="{{ site.baseurl }}/projects">Projects</a>
         </nav>
       </header>
     </div>
   </div>
```

So, my problem is that **title** and **description** are not shown, where as **Blog** , **About me** and **Projects** are shown.  Output on localhost is shown as below

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In your **_config.yml** change `name: amarjit singh` to `title: amarjit singh`.